# How to understand 'Callable[..., nn.Module]'

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

When I read pytorch 1.10 source code, I always encounter the syntax like below :

```
def __init__(
    ...
    norm_layer: Optional[Callable[..., nn.Module]] = None
    ...
)
```

what does this '**Callable[..., nn.Module]**' mean?

and more, these syntax emerges in the new version of pytorch, which doesn't appear in the pytorch 1.7 source code. Why did these syntax be added to the code?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#callable

Comment: Thank you, I was not familiar with this syntax, now I understand Callable is a way to check a callback function of specific signatures, and the ellipsis "..." means not specifying the call signature. In this way, we can assure the return type of norm_layer is nn.Module. I should have consulted the org docs first. Thanks again.